# SQL Server : count duplicates and filter by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a data structure that looks like the equivalent of this

```
UserID| Rating | CreatedDate |
------+--------+-------------+
 101  |  10    |  21-02-2018 |
 101  |  10    |  18-02-2018 |
 102  |   6    |  12-01-2018 |
 103  |   3    |  01-02-2018 |
 101  |   8    |  25-03-2018 |
 102  |   2    |  21-02-2017 |
 101  |   1    |  21-08-2017 |
```

I am trying to retrieve from SQL Server 2017 a count of all the different ratings (1-10) a particular user has given.

I am using this code:

```
 SELECT Rating, COUNT(Rating) AS Count
 FROM dbo.tableName
 GROUP BY Rating, UserId
 HAVING (COUNT(Rating) >= 1) AND (UserId = '101')
 ORDER BY Count DESC
```

The issue I have however is that I wish to only run this query for entries created in the last 5 weeks, to filter to the last 5 weeks I would previously use:

```
(CreatedDateTime > DATEADD(week, - 5, GETDATE())) AND (Recommend IS NOT NULL)
```

but when mixed with `Count`, this is no longer working. I get an error along the line of

> CreatedDateTime is invalid in the having clause because it is not contained in either aggregate function or group by clause

Could someone help me get the correct syntax?

Answer (score 3):

I think your criteria should be in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    Rating,
    COUNT(Rating) AS Count
FROM dbo.tableName
WHERE
    CreatedDateTime > DATEADD(week, - 5, GETDATE()) AND
    Recommend IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Rating,
    UserId
HAVING
    COUNT(Rating) >= 1 AND UserId = '101'
ORDER BY
    Count DESC
```

This should restrict to records only occurring within the last five weeks, and also those records where `Recommend` is not NULL.

The reason you were getting an error is that by the time the `HAVING` clause is being evaluated, the database is dealing with aggregates of records.  Since the `CreatedDateTime` field is not an aggregate, it resulted in an error.

Answer (score 3):

Move your row filters to the `WHERE` and keep you aggregate filters on the `HAVING`.

```
SELECT        
    Rating, 
    COUNT(Rating) AS Count
FROM
    dbo.tableName
WHERE
    UserId = '101' AND
    CreatedDateTime > DATEADD(week, - 5, GETDATE()) AND 
    Recommend IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    Rating
HAVING
    COUNT(Rating) >= 1
ORDER BY
     Count DESC
```

The SQL engine filter filters data with the `WHERE` conditions, then groups the rows with the `GROUP BY` columns, and finally applies `HAVING` conditions to filter the grouped results.

Comment: thanks, I ended up solving by nesting a select by date within a Select/count. But your solution was much more elegant and clean and have replaced my code.